# XSLFO - using xsl:import or xsl:include causes error when creating PDF

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have used XSLFO to generate PDF files, which is working perfectly.

There is some code within the XSLFO that I would like to put into a common file to be used by all the PDF's, but when I add an xsl:import... or xsl:inlcude... at the top of my file, Adobe throws an error saying the file is damaged and cannot be repaired.

Is there something specific I need to do to include another xsl file?  I've tried having it in the same root directory but it's still not working.

I have tried adding a full path to the imported xsl files and that works, rather than the relative path, so is this a permissions issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding an xsl:import or xsl:include to the XSL-FO document, then that's wrong - these declarations should only appear in an XSLT stylesheet file.

Comment: No, there isn't enough information about what you are doing to know what you are doing wrong.